# "EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY" is aways print with each project even it is the new create project? What?

Tags: flutter

After I make a mistake in one project and then print error log:

```
I/flutter (13313): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (13646): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (13646): The following assertion was thrown building TabNavPage(dirty, state: _TabNavPageState#16407):
I/flutter (13646): Every item must have a non-null title
I/flutter (13646): 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar.dart':
I/flutter (13646): Failed assertion: line 193 pos 9: 'items.every((BottomNavigationBarItem item) => item.title != null)
I/flutter (13646): == true'
I/flutter (13646): 
I/flutter (13646): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter (13646): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter (13646): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter (13646):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter (13646): 
I/flutter (13646): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (13646):   TabNavPage file:///home/lfd/Desktop/works/flutter/trip/flutter_trip/lib/main.dart:11:13
```

although I fixed it and run success, it still prints errors. it is also printed in a new project and not have a file name TabNavPage ...
So where is the error log file stored?
What happened??

Comment: There is a widget into your `TabNavPage`class wich needs to have a title specified. Please share your  code for more help

Comment: I had got it. => wipe the emulator data. flutter probably keeps the crash log there.